# Edit text file according to individual rule

Tags: text-processing, files

I'd like to edit a given text file

```
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy,/s-show/...
```

where /s-show/ is in every line, followed by random characters "..."

There are two cases:

1. A line begins with date in "dd.mm.yyyy" format, then there is a comma and whitespace, after that the time in "hh:mm" format follows and in the end there comes /s-show/...
2. A line begins only with the date, followed by only a comma and directly /s-show/...

Every line should be edited like this:

Put three whitespaces in the first case (so if the lines begin with date and time) after hh:mm, and 3 whitespaces after the comma in the second case (if the results begin only with date), and then add the same string "https:/www.test.com" before /s-show/

/s-show/ is a part of a link, and has to be complemented to a valid link by "https:/www.test.com" from the left side.

so the outcome should be something like this in every line:

```
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm   https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm   https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy,   https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
```

How could this be done?
The bonus would be that the links begin at the same place, so in the first case it would be 3 whitespaces and in the second case 9 whatespaces.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to me. Is the string `/s-show/` fixed or only an example? If it is not always `/s-show/`, what exactly is the criteria to distinguish between lines with and without time? Please [edit] your question and clarify this.

Comment: @Bodo I edited it. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: You asked a similar question two days ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607838/edit-text-file-according-to-individual-rule You can use the answer that worked and tweak it to do what you need here.

Comment: Is it not just `sed 's|/|   https:/www.test.com/|'` (insert `"   https:/www.test.com"` before the first occurrence of `/`)?

Comment: @NasirRiley I don't know how to adapt it to this case, unfortunately. Could you maybe help me?

Comment: @X3nion It's important that you give an effort yourself and show where you are having trouble. This isn't a scripting hotline.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the text after the date (and time) will always start with the fixed string `/s-show/`.

```
sed -e 's#^\([^/]\{17\}\)\(/s-show/\)#\1   https:/www.test.com\2#' -e 's#^\([^/]\{11\}\)\(/s-show/\)#\1         https:/www.test.com\2#' inputfile > outputfile
```

**Explanation:**

The script does not check for a date or time, it only requires 17 characters (or 11 characters) different from `/` at the beginning of the line followed by `/s-show/` and inserts the required number of spaces and `https:/www.test.com` between the captured groups.

Note: In `sed`'s substitution (`s`)  command I used the separator `#` instead of the usual `/` to avoid escaping the slashes in the pattern.

**Test:**

```
echo 'dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy,/s-show/...' | sed -e 's#^\([^/]\{17\}\)\(/s-show/\)#\1   https:/www.test.com\2#' -e 's#^\([^/]\{11\}\)\(/s-show/\)#\1         https:/www.test.com\2#'
```

prints

```
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm   https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm   https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
dd.mm.yyyy,         https:/www.test.com/s-show/...
```

Comment: Mhm this code assumes that the text file is of this concrete form of the initial post. But the results change every time, and so there can be 3 hits, 7 hits, ... How could this be solved then?

Comment: @X3nion What exactly "changes every time"? If the `sed` script does not work as expected, please add a second example input to your question where it would fail. If you mean the `echo 'dd.mm.yyyy...' |` part, this of course must be replaced with accessing your real input file.

Comment: Yeah I meant that the input file varies. How would the code look like using the input file instead of the echo command?

Comment: @X3nion See the updated answer. (This is basic knowledge. You should learn about shell commands/scripts.)

Answer (score 0):

Perl is handy for this:

```bsh
perl -pe 's{([^/]+)}{ sprintf "%-17s   https://www.test.com", $1 }e' file
```